# Copy_raster to remove no data value using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I have multiple raster, I am trying to remove Nodata value using Copy_raster option. Since I have multiple raster, I am running a ArcPy script, save the raster as same input name.

But that script, does not allow me to remove the nodata pixel,and

Script below:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')

arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\Argicul\Maize\maize_Yield"

outFolder = r"Argicul\Maize\maize_Yield1"

list = arcpy.ListRasters()

for inRaster in list:
    localRaster = Raster(inRaster)
    outRaster = arcpy.CopyRaster_management( localRaster, nodata_value="0")
    outRaster.save(outFolder + "\\" + inRaster )
```

Comment: Try: [How to change NoData cells to a value](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/h-changing-nodata-cells-to-a-value.htm)

Comment: Thanks, but i am not looking for that which link you sent me. I trying to run the copy raster tool on ArcPy script.

Comment: This command worked for me, changing the nodata value to -999: `arcpy.CopyRaster_management(r"C:\scratch\ppp.tif",r"C:\scratch\ppp2.tif",nodata_value = -999)`

Comment: Thanks, I have multiple raster, how to define that multiple raster list in the functions.